# How to color a MatPlotLib scatter plot based on a list of categories

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, visualization, scatter-plot

I have a Pandas dataframe called DATA, which i passed into a function to categorize two columns from the data (see code below). The result is a list of strings, which is the same length as DATA. The list is separate from the dataframe (i must do it like this because its for an assignment).

I'm trying to create a MatPlotLib scatterplot that plots the two columns in DATA as x and y values:

```
x = DATA.loc[:]['A']
y = DATA.loc[:]['B']
```

I want the plot points to be colored based on their corresponding categories (ie 'Healthy' is green, 'Unhealthy' is red) I also have to include these attributes: `alpha = 0.5, s = 100` How would I go about doing this?

I tried mapping the names of the categories to colors using a color map, and then calling .map on the category list itself, which didn't work because list doesn't have that method. Kinda just took it from a website.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
colors = {"Healthy": "green", "Unhealthy": "blue", "Morbid": "red"}
ax.scatter(x, y, c=[CATEGORIES].map(colors))
```

Comment: Use `ax = sns.scatterplot(data=DATA, x='A', y='B', hue='CATEGORIES', palette=['green', 'blue', 'red'], hue_order=['Healthy', 'Unhealthy', 'Morbid'])` and `import seaborn as sns`. `seaborn` is a high-level API for `matplotlib`. Assumes `'CATEGORIES'` is the column name.

Answer (score 0):

You was almost there. [`.map()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) is a method of a `pandas.Series`. So either convert `CATEGORY` to a `pd.Series` or use a list comprhension:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

DATA = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "A": [1, 2, 3],
        "B": [4, 5, 6],
    }
)
CATEGORY = ["Healthy", "Unhealthy", "Morbid"]

colors_mapping = {"Healthy": "green", "Unhealthy": "blue", "Morbid": "red"}

# Solution 1
colors = [colors_mapping.get(cat, "black") for cat in CATEGORY]
# Solution 2
colors = pd.Series(CATEGORY).map(colors_mapping)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(DATA["A"], DATA["B"], c=colors)
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]